# printing with custom page size and print preview settings for IE/Firefox/Safari

Tags: printing, cross-browser

I am currently trying to add a "Print Label" functionality. After clicking the button, the print preview dialog should open and print in the label format (which is different and hidden from the screen view).

I had tested in chrome, IE, Firefox and safari in Windows 7. However, only chrome works as expected, printing in the expected page size and style. For IE and Firefox, although the label format stays intact when I save in PDF, I can only print in the letter (default) page size, which means a disaster when I use the label printer to print. When I attempt to change the page size to the custom label size, IE crashes while Firefox does not let me open the properties in the system print dialog. For safari (IN WINDOWS), I can print in the custom label size, however, I cannot remove the header and footer, resulting the label format to split into many pages.

The questions I have are: 
1. Is the culprit the custom label size, or is it because of the limitations of the other browsers? 
2. How can I remove headers and footers in Safari (windows)? My findings are pessimistic about that for now... 
3. Are there any ways for me to generate print preview dialog, instead of print dialog, for other browsers? (Something like chrome)
4. Are there any ways for me to use Javascript to preset print settings, to set the printer to the label printer and change page size to the custom label size?

Thanks if anyone can enlighten me.